# Expected value for $a^x$

Tags: probability

Assume a random variable $X$. Assume, if this simplifies the problem, that $X$ can take only non negative integer values. Does there exist any relation between $E(X)$ and $E(a^X)$, where $a$ is an arbitrary value in the interval $[0,1]$ and by $a^X$ I mean the random variable that takes value $a^x$ with the same probability $p$ such that $X$ takes probability $x$?

Thanks!

Comment: We cannot find $E(a^X)$ just knowing $a$ and $E(X)$. Inequalities might be possible.

Comment: Indeed, this is just the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ where $t=\log a$.

Answer (score 2):

$$E(X) = \lim_{a \to 1} \dfrac{d}{da} E(a^X)$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple relation between $E[f(X)]$ and $E[X]$ for any convex function $f$, namely $f(E[X]) \leq E[f(X)]$.  This holds for any random variable X and holds with strict inequality if X is not degenerate.  Hence, since $a^x$ is convex, we have that $a^{E[X]} \leq E[a^X]$ or $E[X] \leq log_a(E[a^X])$.